# NavigationLink onTapGesture and navigation not firing consistently

Tags: swiftui

In a SwiftUI view I implemented a vertically scrolling list by creating a VStack that contains a NavigationView that contains some text.  I build this by looping through a popularFeedTypes object creating a NavigationLink for each item in the popularFeedTypes object.  If a user clicks on the NavigationLink the user is pushed to a new view called FeedTypeView.  You can see the code below.

```
VStack{
    NavigationView{
        List (self.popularFeedTypes.popularFeedTypes!, id: \.self) { feedType in
            NavigationLink(destination: FeedTypeView(feedType: feedType)) {
                Text(feedType.feedType)
            }.onTapGesture {
                print("TAPPED")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Discover"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that if I have an onTapGesture action on the NavigationLink, I experience a different behavior from within the simulator depending upon how I click the row.  If I click on the text or on the arrow (>) at the right hand side of the row, the onTapGesture fires off but no navigation occurs. If I click on the space between the text and the arrow, onTapGesture does not fire but navigation occurs.  If I remove the onTapGesture code, clicking any of the three places causes navigation to occur.  So my question is shouldn't navigation occur even with an onTapGesture action existing?  Also shouldn't the onTapGesture action fire off regardless of where you click on the row that makes up the NavigationLink?

Comment: NavigationLink is essentially a button so it responds to touches, when you add a tap geture onto it you have a single view that is trying to respond to two touches at the same time. What is the use of the tap gesture? Maybe it could be achieved in a better way?

Comment: The desire was to query some data based upon the user click and load it into an environmentobject

Comment: Why not kick it off in onApear() in your destination?

Comment: I guess that would work as well, I was thinking I needed to make some decisions before proceeding to the next view, but that can probably be handled another way.  I am still curious though, if it is possible to have customized logic fired off during a click prior to navigating to another view.

Comment: Handling various touches is very tricky. You could also have a `Button` and a `NavaigationLinink` over an `EmptyView` with `isActive` flag. Then you could handle anything you wanted to in `onTapGesture` in the `Button`'s action and set `isActive` to true as the last thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
VStack {
    NavigationView{
        List (self.popularFeedTypes.popularFeedTypes!, id: \.self) { feedType in
            NavigationLink(destination: FeedTypeView(feedType: feedType)) {
                Text(feedType.feedType)
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                print("TAPPED")
            })
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Discover"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

This should work. use `simultaneousGesture` on `NavigationLink`

Comment: Should work? Have you tried it? It is not working with me.

Comment: @MatheusCâmara  - This code is working for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use onAppear to handle tapped event.

```swift
VStack {
    NavigationView {
        List(self.popularFeedTypes.popularFeedTypes!, id: \.self) { feedType in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: FeedTypeView(feedType: feedType).onAppear { print("TAPPED") }) {
                Text(feedType.feedType)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Discover"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform both action and navigation simultaneously you can do this:

```
VStack{
        NavigationView{
            List (self.popularFeedTypes.popularFeedTypes!, id: \.self) { feedType in
                NavigationLink(destination: FeedTypeView(feedType: feedType)) {
                    Text(feedType.feedType)
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                    print("TAPPED")
                })
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Discover"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me unfortunately, but did sound promising

Comment: How this solution working for you ? I have tried and it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm for me on the latest Swift/SwiftUI. I use a LazyVStack instead of List though so it could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something before your navigation link is triggered, you can initialize a navigation link with `tag` and `selection`.

```
struct someViewName: View {
    
    @State var navigationLinkTriggerer: Bool? = nil
    @State var navigationLinkFeedType: FeedType
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: FeedTypeView(feedType: navigationLinkFeedType),
                           tag: true,
                           selection: $navigationLinkTriggerer) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                List (self.popularFeedTypes.popularFeedTypes!, id: \.self) { feedType in
                    Button(feedType) {
                        // do all you want here
                        print("TAPPED")
                        // then set the navigationLinkTriggerer to value of you navigation link `tag`
                        // in this case tag is equal to `true`
                        // this will trigger the navigation link
                        self.navigationLinkFeedType = feedType
                        self.navigationLinkTriggerer = true
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Discover"), displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```